# Is there any simple way to bookmark directly into a folder?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bookmarks

I've been using Google Chrome for quite a while and I've got quite large amount of bookmark folders.

[image]

The problem is, whenever I want to bookmark a site to a specific folder, I have to first click the *star* and select a folder, it only gives me the 5 recent ones

[image]

Sorry for the screenshot not being in english, but I guess anyone using Chrome can understand what I mean.

The problem is, that every time I have to click on *Choose different folder* and then select it from the popup dialog. Isn't it possible to just somehow drag & drop the tab into a bookmark folder, as you can do in Firefox?

I'm using Chrome 15 on Windows Vista. For Mac users, you can already see the whole list of bookmarks, so this issue is Windows specific.

Comment: What is your Chrome version? I'm on Chrome 15 and all my folders are shown, not just the 5 recent ones.

Comment: I'm on 15 too, but they don't show (Windows). However on my Mac where I have Chrome 14, it displays all of them.

Comment: You might want to edit those information into the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking the star to bookmark the page, drag the icon on the left side of the location bar (just to the left of the URL you're visiting) and drop it in the folder on the bookmarks bar where you want it.